# Java stream filter 2 level List<Object>

Tags: java, java-stream

I have 2 classes `A` and `B`

`class A`

```
{
  int id,
  List<B>
}
```

`class B`

```
{
  int id
}
```

Now given `List<A>`, I want filter out all `B.id` > 3

ex.

`List<A>`:

```
{
  [
    id: 1,
    Bs: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  ],
  [
    id: 2,
    Bs: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  ]
}
```

expected result is

```
{
  [
    id: 1,
    Bs: [1, 2, 3]
  ],
  [
    id: 2,
    Bs: [1, 2, 3]
  ]
}
```

How to do with `stream, filter`? thanks!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not use simple for-loops:

```
for (A a : listOfAs) {
    a.listOfBs.removeIf(b -> b.id > 3);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you need a `Stream`, since you are not filtering out any elements of the input `List<A>`, and there's no reason to produce a new `List<A>`.

Just iterate over the elements of the input `List<A>` and remove elements from the inner `List<B>` lists via `removeIf()`:

```
List<A> as = ...
as.forEach(a -> a.getBList().removeIf(b -> b.getId() > 3));
```